# How do I calculate mean of a column but only including certain rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, mean

I'm working using automobile.csv which can be found in the UCI website. I want to replace some NaNs in normalized losses attribute. I figured that a better way of doing it is by calculating the mean according to the symboling because symboling affects the value of normalized losses.

So if the NaN have a symboling of 3 I only want mean of other normalized losses that have value 3 as their symboling. How do I achieve this?

example
table:

```
symb    norm    other attrs
1        100  8017  2
1        90  5019  2
-1       20   8017  1
-1       20    8870  1
1        NaN    8305  3
0        10   8305  3
3        200  8221  3
```

so for NaN I only want mean from other rows with the same symboling

if i use

```
automobile['normalizedlosses'].fillna(automobile['normalizedlosses'].mean(axis=0), inplace=True)
```

This would replace all NaN with the same value which I don't want

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @jezrael yes that worked. thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` for return `Series` with same size like original DataFrame,so possible use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by this `Series`:

```
s = automobile.groupby('symb')['norm'].transform('mean')
automobile['norm'] = automobile['norm'].fillna(s)

print (automobile)
   symb   norm  other  attrs
0     1  100.0   8017      2
1     1   90.0   5019      2
2    -1   20.0   8017      1
3    -1   20.0   8870      1
4     1   95.0   8305      3
5     0   10.0   8305      3
6     3  200.0   8221      3
```